# Move a 3D custom geometry: the best way to do it

Tags: c#, optimization, 3d, xna

I'm building with XNA a class that encapsulate a custom geometry defined in a arbitrary way. I want to this geometry moves, now, what is the best way to do it?
Is it enough bring all coordinates vertices and multiply them with the translate matrix using Vector3.Translate method? Or is it more efficient assign a geometry to an Effect (say BasicEffect) and then manipulate the world matrix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that deep into xna right now, but speaking of 3D programming in general you should transform the world matrix to "move" the object's origin. This will be a lot faster than updating all vertices to their new coordinates (a LOT faster as the calculation can be offloaded to the graphics card). You should never modify/update geometry data just to move stuff around. This might be okay for complex animations, but (in my opinion) not for single translations.

Comment: maybe it is a stupid question, but, what happens if I have multiple moving objects onto screen? Traslate the world matrix implies a translation in all the elements in the world

Comment: @Archedius Only if you apply it to all the elements in the world! Set it for your first object, draw that object, set it for your second object, draw, etc.

Comment: Archedius: Think the other direction. Does it sound more efficient to you? Move vertices, draw, reset vertices, move them again, draw again, etc. That's also the reason why there are multiple matrixes (view, projection and world): That way it's a lot easier to change single things, e.g. the position of the object without having to update the camera as well.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the answer, now my ideas are completely clear! :)